# Looping over file names with Python

Tags: python, json, loops, path

I have 200 files I want to modify with Python named "1.json", "2.json", "3.json"... and I am trying to create a loop to open and modify them. I did not manage to do it with "for i in range(1, 200):" so I tried the following way.

```
myList = {"1.json", "2.json", "3.json"}
for toImport in myList:
    with open("path1" + toImport) as f:
        json_response = json.load(f)


for data in json_response:
    try:
        for special_issue in data["specific_issues"]:
            for x in special_issue["bills_by_algo"]:
                resulting_data.append(({"id": x["id"], "committees": x["committees"]}))

    except KeyError as e:
        print(e, "not found in entry.")
        continue

b = pd.DataFrame(resulting_data)
print(b)
b.to_csv(r"path2" +toImport)
```

Now it does not make an error message anymore, but the files are not exported... What should I change?

Comment: I have corrected the indent error and it works. However I still can't export the files... I have added the code line on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit, I have to edit the answer:

I guess you have to indent all your response handling code to the for loop, since the `json_response` is overwritten after each iteration.

```py
myList = {"1.json", "2.json", "3.json"}
for toImport in myList:

    with open("path1" + toImport) as f:
        json_response = json.load(f)

    resulting_data = []
    for data in json_response:
        try:
            for special_issue in data["specific_issues"]:
                for x in special_issue["bills_by_algo"]:
                    resulting_data.append(
                        ({"id": x["id"], "committees": x["committees"]})
                    )

        except KeyError as e:
            print(e, "not found in entry.")
            continue

    b = pd.DataFrame(resulting_data)
    print(b)
    b.to_csv(r"path2" + toImport)
```

---

Old answer before question edit:

You have a small SyntaxError, because your code below the for... needs to be indented.

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

myList = {"1.json", "2.json", "3.json"}
for toImport in myList:
    with open("path" + toImport) as f:
        json_response = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have changed it and it works. However I still can't export the files...
I have added the code line on the post.

Comment: Maybe my edit works, you most likely need to indent your JSON data code in your initial for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just indent the last two lines.

Python requires code blocks to be indented. In this case, since you want the with sentence in the loop, you'll want it indented along with it's dependents

Comment: Thanks Marlow, could you please explain what you mean by indenting?

Comment: Indenting is adding some padding to the left of the line, like a paragraph! It's usually 4 spaces OR a tab

Answer (score 1):

There is an Indentation error. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
myList = {'1.json', '2.json', '3.json'}
for toImport in myList:
    with open('path'+toImport) as f:
        json_response = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an indentation error as pointed out by other answers. But the code is not good as you will have to list all the files by hand. Here is a more complete solution which loops over a folder and process JSON files only:

```
import os

folder = os.path.join('.', 'path/to/data')

for r, d, f in os.walk(folder):
    for file in f:
        if '.json' in file:
            with open(file) as f:
                # do things with f
```